# Perl Catalyst, pass to stash 2 template parts

Tags: perl, catalyst

I started learning Perl Catalyst and it's awesome!!! However, I am having a little issue here with templating.

I am trying to pass two template variables to the page (header and footer), what I did in the Controller function is

```
$c->stash(template => 'header.html');
//other page contents
$c->stash(template => 'footer.html');
```

but this only outputs the footer.html (which it should and seems logical)

What would be the way for this approach? I searched google but could not find many helpful results (at least results that I could understand and use)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a view.

[https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Manual::Tutorial::02_CatalystBasics#Hello-World-Using-a-View-and-a-Template](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst%3a%3aManual%3a%3aTutorial%3a:02_CatalystBasics#Hello-World-Using-a-View-and-a-Template)

Also, have a look at how wrappers work in TT -- they are really cool.

http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Directives.html#section_WRAPPER

Comment: I have a view called HTML but I don't get what it has to do with the template because the name is not included anywhere.

Comment: Follow the tutorial I linked you to. It will guide you through precisely what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass 2 templates in stash.Only the last value will be kept.However the to way to do this, is to include the footer template inside the header.The commands `include` and `process` are very helpfull.